# Have background music that doesn't restart as a user clicks between pages

Tags: html, css, jquery, plugin, audio

Yeah I know, background music sucks. Bottom line, client wants it.

I need to know how to keep it playing when going through the pages.

I'm using a QuickTime plugin for the time being but I noticed that Windows XP will use media player controls if the QuickTime plugin is not installed. This is also a problem in formatting the size.

How do I keep it playing and not start over?

Also, is there a better solution than using DW plugins?

Comment: Why don't you convince your client that background music is a bad idea instead. See this page for some arguments: https://moz.com/blog/how-to-convince-a-client-their-site-doesnt-need-music

Comment: Kill the client, seriously, some people are too stupid to live!

Comment: Did you guys just want to weigh in on what I already said that background music sucks or do have something of value to add?

Answer (score 1):

The only player I know that has such an autoresume feature, that bookmarks the exit point and picks it up on the next page is [XSPF](http://www.boutell.com/xspf/).

Aside from that the only **other** way is the horrible, horrible, broken, nasty way - A frameset, the audio plays in one frame and other pages load in another.

Comment: Oh well, maybe by seeing that the music will keep starting over will be enough to discourage the use of background music. Thanks!

Comment: @Ibanez - I mean XSPF will do exactly what you want, keep the music playing through the page loads and do it without the frameset.

Comment: I suppose you could also just AJAX the entire site...

Comment: @toomanyairmiles I looked at XSPF before posting here. I couldn't figure out how to make it work. The guy's website is too confusing.